# IP Address using PHP not reliable

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, codeigniter, geolocation

I use a javascript API from (http://www.iplocationtools.com) to give me the location data from a visitors IP.  For some reason, their API won't give me the actual IP of the visitor, just the other info, which is why I have to use PHP and CodeIgniter to give me the IP instead.

So I use CodeIgniter/PHP to get the IP of a visitor and add it to the database along with location data from above by using PHP's ip2long([the ip code igniter gives me])

I'm confused when my database table looks like this: http://pulse.media.mit.edu/images/1.png

Which is wrong?  I'm tempted to believe CodeIgniter is wrong since it gives me the same IP so many times.  Age and sex are self reported and I doubt one person is making up all this information.

At the end of the day, all we really need is the users IP and location, preferably from the same source, so we don't compound errors.

Anybody have a better idea on how to do this?

EDIT:  Here is the code that I'm using to get the IP address from CodeIgniter

```
$data['ip_address'] = ip2long($this->input->ip_address());
$this->pulse_model->voter_info($data);
```

Then the voter_info function just inserts it into the database where it's stored as an INT(11).

And here is the function ip_address:

function ip_address()
    {
        if ($this->ip_address !== FALSE)
        {
            return $this->ip_address;
        }

```
    if (config_item('proxy_ips') != '' && $this->server('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') && $this->server('REMOTE_ADDR'))
    {
        $proxies = preg_split('/[\s,]/', config_item('proxy_ips'), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $proxies = is_array($proxies) ? $proxies : array($proxies);

        $this->ip_address = in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $proxies) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    elseif ($this->server('REMOTE_ADDR') AND $this->server('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
    {
        $this->ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif ($this->server('REMOTE_ADDR'))
    {
        $this->ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    elseif ($this->server('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
    {
        $this->ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif ($this->server('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
    {
        $this->ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }

    if ($this->ip_address === FALSE)
    {
        $this->ip_address = '0.0.0.0';
        return $this->ip_address;
    }

    if (strpos($this->ip_address, ',') !== FALSE)
    {
        $x = explode(',', $this->ip_address);
        $this->ip_address = trim(end($x));
    }

    if ( ! $this->valid_ip($this->ip_address))
    {
    $this->ip_address = '0.0.0.0';
    }
    return $this->ip_address;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using to get the IP Address with CodeIgniter/PHP?

Comment: The number all of your IPs have is the max value for 32 bit signed integers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647#2147483647_in_computing) so my thought is either codeigniter is giving you something like 255.255.255.255 for everyone's IP, or you're mishandling it somewhere between getting it from codeigniter and storing it in the DB. Did you try echo-ing the IP address you're getting from codeigniter to see if it's valid?

Comment: I added the code segment above.

Comment: Can you confirm that `$this->input->ip_address()` returns a valid IP address?

Comment: There is a function valid_ip() but if that returns false, I still need the users IP to keep track of where they are in the world.  Is that not possible?  The javascript API I was using before seems to resolve most users to a location.  Are they making that up if I can't even get an IP?  It would be easier if they just let me have the IP of the visitor, but they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, it looks like `$this->input->ip_address()` has the possibility of returning '0.0.0.0' if the IP is not valid or could not be determined. However, your comments also state that you need to record the ip address even if the above method returns '0.0.0.0'.

First, I'd recommend checking to see if `$this->input->ip_address()` and `$this->valid_ip()` are working as expected. Is `$this->valid_ip()` returning false for IP's that should be considered valid?

Second, I'd update your code to always fall back to `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` if `$this->input->ip_address()` returns '0.0.0.0'.

```
$ip_address = $this->input->ip_address();
if($ip_address == '0.0.0.0') {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$data['ip_address'] = ip2long($ip_address);
$this->pulse_model->voter_info($data);
```

Or if you wanted, you could not use `$this->input->ip_address()` and do as @rockerest suggests and just use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to being with.

```
$data['ip_address'] = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$this->pulse_model->voter_info($data);
```

Answer (score 6):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the PHP code to return the IP address of the person viewing the page.

Answer (score 2):

Old versions of `ip2long()` will return -1 if the IPv4 address is invalid. You may want to use [`inet_pton`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) instead and expand the field used to hold it to 128 bits.